# Checks for the true condition in for loop to store in datatable

Tags: c#, sql

A `for` loop for the true condition sends a parameter to stored procedure and then required result is stored in a `DataTable`. Now my problem is at every loop the value in the `DataTable` gets refreshed with new value and previous value gets lost. How to retain all the value of true condition in the `DataTable`?

```
for (int i = 0; i < gridview1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string yojnaNo = "";
    CheckBox chl = (CheckBox)gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("CheckBox1");

    if (chl != null)
    {
        if (chl.Checked == true)
        {
            int rowsNo = (Convert.ToInt16(chl.ToolTip) - 1); //Convert.ToInt16(SrNo);
            yojnaNo = ((Label)gridview1.Rows[rowsNo].FindControl("lblYojnaNo")).Text;
            sc.Add(yojnaNo);
        }
    }

    objyojnadetail4.YojnaNo = sc;
    DataTable city = objyojnadetail4.Selectcity();
}
```

Comment: Put your code here. How do you think people understand your problem clearly? [faq] and [ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put the instantiation of city on the outside and add each rows into it in every loop. You won't lose the value, instead, the `city` will getting bigger each loop.

```
DataTable city = new DataTable(); // instantiate here
for (int i = 0; i < gridview1.Rows.Count; i++)
{
    string yojnaNo = "";
    CheckBox chl = (CheckBox)gridview1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FindControl("CheckBox1");

    if (chl != null)
    {
        if (chl.Checked == true)
        {
            int rowsNo = (Convert.ToInt16(chl.ToolTip) - 1); //Convert.ToInt16(SrNo);
            yojnaNo = ((Label)gridview1.Rows[rowsNo].FindControl("lblYojnaNo")).Text;
            sc.Add(yojnaNo);
        }
    }

    objyojnadetail4.YojnaNo = sc;

    // this foreach loop may loop on anything the objyojnadetail4.Selectcity() provides
    // what was important is that, in this loop you insert each data into rows in city.
    foreach(var singleItem in objyojnadetail4.Selectcity().Rows)
    {
        city.Rows.Add(singleItem);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanx for the answer @didityedi but now no data is binding in the grid view

Comment: will u please check ur code again foreach because maybe it is not sending the parameter to function Selectcity()

Comment: @Himanshu so now no data is binding? Is it because the instantiation of city is outside the loop? I have edited the answer so it mimics your code. Please view again.

Comment: problem remains the data is not binding

Comment: on your code before, did it bind? maybe you could check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/425424/databinding-to-a-programmaticly-created-datatable for your problem in databinding.